# reading txt storing in different

Tags: asp.net, waithandle

ASp.NET application.
In button click i am accessing one text file and reading content and storing in other destination.

while both users clicking this button at a time deadlock(thread is being used by other process) will occurs so how to handle this i want to read each user one by one can any one suggest method to handle.
  i am looking to handle with waithandle events so can any one give a code sample for above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to synchronize access to a shared resource such as a file.